# What credentialType is "Secret Text"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a pipeline script for a parametrized job which accepts a "Secret Text" type credential as an input.

I tried:
`credentials(name: 'API_TOKEN', description: 'API Access Token', defaultValue: '', credentialType: "Secret Text", required: true )`

But when it generates the input configuration for my job, a credential type filter is set to "Any".

[image]

If I change it manually to "Secret text" from GUI, fitering is working correctly, but I cannot force my pipeline script to set a correct value at the beginning so filtering is not working and all the credentials are displayed.

What should I provide as `credentialType: ???`.

I see in some web pages that simple text is used there eg. `credentialType: "Username with password"` but some people use full class names like `credentialType: com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl`

Comment: Why does the credential need to be a parameter? Are you expecting the user to decide which credential is required?

Comment: Each user has his own access token stored in a private Jenkins credentials store. I would like to provide a way to pick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
I found correct values using Jenkins console with help of this page:

https://www.dennisotugo.com/how-to-view-all-jenkins-secrets-credentials/

Apparently the correct value for "Secret Text" is: "org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl"